# Saving variables from multiple classes to file

Tags: c++, structure, game-engine

For my current project I want to eventually be able to save the game state to a file.

I'm looking to have a pretty simple system where I store the required variable data in ASCII format.
 But. How do I gather all the variables?

Do I

- Pass the ofstream (file stream) object around to all the required classes?
- Fetch the variables through some getter-methods?
- Store them all in one place?
- Other?

Of course, I will also have to initialize the vars from the file later.

I seem to have a hard time making a decision here. So I'm humbly asking for some tips.

Cheers!

Comment: All of the answers you'll receive will be pretty opinion-based so maybe not the best question for SO. However, I'll give my opinion anyway: I think fetching data from getters is NOT a good idea since you can have different objects that save differently. I think the best option is to have Save function for each object you want to save to the file and call the save function for all the save-able objects in your level. With this in mind, it is probably best to store all of the save-able objects to some data structure and pass the file stream object to each one of these iteratively

Comment: Yeah, I guess this is not really the place for these questions. Thanks for the answer though - seems reasonable.

Comment: Store the data in a format, such as XML or Init.  Use a library to read and write the data.  Also search the internet for "C++ struct serialization".

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** I haven't used C++ in ages so the use of syntax/library functions is not entirely accurate. Hopefully it does deliver the idea, though.

Design patterns to the rescue! Register some handlers into a `Save` class which will save each of the variables for you.

First, we define an [interface](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_interfaces.htm):

```
class ISerializable {
public:
    virtual std::vector<byte> serialize() { throw new NotImplementedException; }
}
```

Next, we write our `Save` class to save each of the handlers:

```
class Save {
    std::map<std::string, ISerializable> handlers;

public:
    void save(string filename) {
        // Open file as writeable bytes
        std::ofstream outFile(filename, std::binary | std::trunc);

        // You may want to use an iterator here.
        // I forgot the exact syntax.
        // pair.Key is the name
        // pair.Value is the class you are saving
        foreach(pair in handlers) {
            // This is an example.
            // Your actual file format will be a bit more complicated than this.
            outFile << "Name: " << pair.Key
                << "Data: " << pair.Value.serialize();
        }
    }

    void attachHandler(std::string name, ISerializable handler) {
        handlers[name] = handler;
    }
}
```

Then for each variable you want to save, define a serialize function for its class:

```
class MyObject : public ISerializable {
public:
    std::vector<byte> serialize override {
        // return some list of bytes
    }
}
```

And attach its handler to a `Save` instance:

```
Save save; // Instantiate your saving object.
           // Consider making this static.

MyObject myObject;
save.attachHandler("myObject", myObject);
```

You might want to consider XML as a storage format: storing raw bytes can be tricky if not done right.